# Details of code-first database are not getting updated in App_Data are not getting updated through update-database in Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I was trying to `update-database` from NuGet Package Manager Console, but database details are not getting filled in App_Data Folder in ASP.NET WEBFORM using MasterPage.

Code on NuGet Package Manager Consoleon updating database

```
PM> enable-migrations -Force -ContextTypeName WebForm.Models.SchoolContext
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project WebForm.
PM> add-migration initial
Scaffolding migration 'initial'.
The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration initial' again.
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [202101311548433_initial].
Applying explicit migration: 202101311548433_initial.
Running Seed method.
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
PM> update-database -force -verbose
Using StartUp project 'WebForm'.
Using NuGet project 'WebForm'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'WebForm.Models.SchoolContext' (DataSource: .\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Convention).
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
PM> add-migration StudentDataTable
Scaffolding migration 'StudentDataTable'.
The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration StudentDataTable' again.
PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [202101311611249_StudentDataTable].
Applying explicit migration: 202101311611249_StudentDataTable.
Running Seed method.
```

Models/StudentsModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebForm.Models
{
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }
    public class Student
    {
        [Key, Display(Name = "E-Mail Id")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(40), Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(20), Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(50), Display(Name = "E-Mail Id")]
        public String Email { get; set; }
        [EnumDataType(typeof(AcademicYear)), Display(Name = "Academic Year")]
        public AcademicYear Year { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

    }
    public class Enrollment
    {
        [Key]
        public int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public decimal? Grade { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
    public class Course
    {
        [Key]
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
    public enum AcademicYear
    {
        Freshman,
        Associate,
        Junior,
        Senior

    }
}
```

Models/IdentityModels.cs

```
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using WebForm.Models;

namespace WebForm.Models
{
    // You can add User data for the user by adding more properties to your User class, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }

        public Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(GenerateUserIdentity(manager));
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}

#region Helpers
namespace WebForm
{
    public static class IdentityHelper
    {
        // Used for XSRF when linking external logins
        public const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

        public const string ProviderNameKey = "providerName";
        public static string GetProviderNameFromRequest(HttpRequest request)
        {
            return request.QueryString[ProviderNameKey];
        }

        public const string CodeKey = "code";
        public static string GetCodeFromRequest(HttpRequest request)
        {
            return request.QueryString[CodeKey];
        }

        public const string UserIdKey = "userId";
        public static string GetUserIdFromRequest(HttpRequest request)
        {
            return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(request.QueryString[UserIdKey]);
        }

        public static string GetResetPasswordRedirectUrl(string code, HttpRequest request)
        {
            var absoluteUri = "/Account/ResetPassword?" + CodeKey + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);
            return new Uri(request.Url, absoluteUri).AbsoluteUri.ToString();
        }

        public static string GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(string code, string userId, HttpRequest request)
        {
            var absoluteUri = "/Account/Confirm?" + CodeKey + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code) + "&" + UserIdKey + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userId);
            return new Uri(request.Url, absoluteUri).AbsoluteUri.ToString();
        }

        private static bool IsLocalUrl(string url)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) && ((url[0] == '/' && (url.Length == 1 || (url[1] != '/' && url[1] != '\\'))) || (url.Length > 1 && url[0] == '~' && url[1] == '/'));
        }

        public static void RedirectToReturnUrl(string returnUrl, HttpResponse response)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                response.Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                response.Redirect("~/");
            }
        }
    }
}
#endregion
```

Configuration.cs

```
namespace WebForm.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using WebForm.Models;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<WebForm.Models.SchoolContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(WebForm.Models.SchoolContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
            context.Students.AddOrUpdate(
                s => s.FirstName,
                new Student
                {
                    StudentId = 1,
                    FirstName = "Raja",
                    LastName = "Singh",
                    Email = "raja123@gmail.com",
                    Year = AcademicYear.Freshman
                },
                new Student
                {
                    StudentId = 2,
                    FirstName = "Rajni",
                    LastName = "Chautala",
                    Email = "rajniips@yahoo.com",
                    Year = AcademicYear.Associate
                },
                new Student
                {
                    StudentId = 3,
                    FirstName = "Nakul",
                    LastName = "Kaushal",
                    Email = "nakul124@gmail.com",
                    Year = AcademicYear.Senior
                },
                new Student
                {
                    StudentId = 4,
                    FirstName = "Samyukta",
                    LastName = "Jain",
                    Email = "Samyukta999@gmail.com",
                    Year = AcademicYear.Junior
                },
                new Student
                {
                    StudentId = 5,
                    FirstName = "Prateeksha",
                    LastName = "Sharma",
                    Email = "Prateeksha3@yahoo.com",
                    Year = AcademicYear.Associate
                },
                new Student
                {
                    StudentId = 6,
                    FirstName = "Pooja",
                    LastName = "Malik",
                    Email = "pooja1212@gmail.com",
                    Year = AcademicYear.Freshman
                },
                new Student
                {
                    StudentId = 7,
                    FirstName = "Mukul",
                    LastName = "Dubey",
                    Email = "mukulmi25@gmail.com",
                    Year = AcademicYear.Associate
                },
                new Student
                {
                    StudentId = 8,
                    FirstName = "Medha",
                    LastName = "Verma",
                    Email = "medha91@yahoo.com",
                    Year = AcademicYear.Junior
                },
                new Student
                {
                    StudentId = 9,
                    FirstName = "Shashankshekhar",
                    LastName = "Singh",
                    Email = "shashank30@gmail.com",
                    Year = AcademicYear.Associate
                },
                new Student
                {
                    StudentId = 10,
                    FirstName = "Prahalad",
                    LastName = "Verma",
                    Email = "Prahalad10@outlook.com",
                    Year = AcademicYear.Senior
                },
                new Student
                {
                    StudentId = 11,
                    FirstName = "Shirley",
                    LastName = "Setha",
                    Email = "shirleysethia@gmail.com",
                    Year = AcademicYear.Junior
                },
                new Student
                {
                    StudentId = 12,
                    FirstName = "Tanishka",
                    LastName = "Singh",
                    Email = "tanishka029@gmail.com",
                    Year = AcademicYear.Associate
                }
                );
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Courses.AddOrUpdate
                (
                c => c.Title,
                new Course
                {
                    CourseId = 1,
                    Title = "Chemistry",
                    Credits = 2
                },
                new Course
                {
                    CourseId = 2,
                    Title = "Macreconomics",
                    Credits = 3
                },
                new Course
                {
                    CourseId = 3,
                    Title = "Mathematics",
                    Credits = 1
                },
                new Course
                {
                    CourseId = 4,
                    Title = "Computer Science and Applications",
                    Credits = 1
                },
                new Course
                {
                    CourseId = 5,
                    Title = "Physics",
                    Credits = 3
                },
                new Course
                {
                    CourseId = 6,
                    Title = "Hindi",
                    Credits = 2
                },
                new Course
                {
                    CourseId = 7,
                    Title = "French",
                    Credits = 2
                },
                new Course
                {
                    CourseId = 8,
                    Title = "Telegu",
                    Credits = 1
                }
                );
            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Enrollments.AddOrUpdate
                (
                e => e.EnrollmentId,
                new Enrollment
                {
                    EnrollmentId = 1,
                    StudentId = 1,
                    CourseId = 1,
                    Grade = 1
                },
                new Enrollment
                {
                    EnrollmentId = 2,
                    StudentId = 2,
                    CourseId = 2,
                    Grade = 3
                },
                new Enrollment
                {
                    EnrollmentId = 3,
                    StudentId = 3,
                    CourseId = 3,
                    Grade = 2
                },
                new Enrollment
                {
                    EnrollmentId = 4,
                    StudentId = 4,
                    CourseId =4,
                    Grade = 1
                },
                new Enrollment
                {
                    EnrollmentId = 5,
                    StudentId = 5,
                    CourseId = 5,
                    Grade = 2
                },
                new Enrollment
                {
                    EnrollmentId = 6,
                    StudentId = 6,
                    CourseId = 6,
                    Grade = 1
                },
                new Enrollment
                {
                    EnrollmentId = 7,
                    StudentId = 7,
                    CourseId = 7,
                    Grade = 1
                },
                new Enrollment
                {
                    EnrollmentId = 8,
                    StudentId = 8,
                    CourseId = 8,
                    Grade = 3
                },
                new Enrollment
                {
                    EnrollmentId = 9,
                    StudentId = 9,
                    CourseId = 2
                },
                new Enrollment
                {
                    EnrollmentId = 10,
                    StudentId = 10,
                    CourseId = 1
                },
                new Enrollment
                {
                    EnrollmentId = 11,
                    StudentId = 11,
                    CourseId = 9,
                    Grade = 4
                },
                new Enrollment
                {
                    EnrollmentId = 12,
                    StudentId = 12,
                    CourseId = 5,
                    Grade = 1
                }
                );
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
}
```